# Extending Marionette.Application with module definitions

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I've been writing an application of mine using Marionette, but I feel a bit confused that application extensions are failing.

There seems to be no way to do this sort of thing in MarionetteJS:

```
var SuperApplication = Backbone.Marionette.Application.extend({
    'modules': {
        'foo': function (module, app) {
            // module definition
        },
        'bar': function (module, app) {
            // module definition
        }
    }
});

var app = new SuperApplication();
```

While I have been developing, it has become important to occasionally create a new `Application` instance and call `.module` numerous times before the application object becomes useful. It negatively affects testing reliability of each `Application` object created, because there are no guarantees that they are of the same prototype.

The following method, ugly as it is, cannot properly attach a module definition to an `Application` as a prototype:

```
SecondApplication = Backbone.Marionette.Application.extend({
    'foo': function () {
        var args = slice(arguments);
        args.unshift(this);
        args.push(function (module, app) {
            // module definition
        });
        return Backbone.Marionette.Module.create.apply(
            Backbone.Marionette.Module, args);
    }
});
```

Am I supposed to do this some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### EDIT: [Marionette modules are now deprecated and will be removed in the next major release](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.7/marionette.module.html)

Use [ES6/CommonJS/AMD modules](https://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/) instead. Capability sharing can be accomplished in vanilla JavaScript using [prototypical inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) or [composition](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/the-open-minded-explorer-s-guide-to-object-composition-88fe68961bed#.8wit6r2uj).

---

#### Original answer (Marionette pre 2.0)

You're right, you can't create modules like that; you have to use the `App.module()` pattern.

It's unusual that you're creating multiple application instances. Your typical setup has a single `Application` instance with `Modules` and sub`Modules` used to partition the site into logical areas, like so:

```
var MyApp = new Marionette.Application();

MyApp.module('forums', function(mod, app) {});
MyApp.module('gallery', function(mod, app) {});
MyApp.module('gallery.kitchen', function(mod, app) {});
MyApp.module('gallery.diningroom', function(mod, app) {});

MyApp.start();
```

If you want numerous modules to have similar capability (or to have the same initial definition), the `module` method can be called multiple times with the same module name to change the functionality. This can be used to create a `base module` of sorts that can be extended:

```
var MyApp = new Marionette.Application();

// Create your shared definition:
var ModuleDefaults = { definition: function(mod, app) {
  mod.type = 'gallery';
  mod.addInitializer(function() { /* do work */ });
}};
// create your modules (quickly!)
_.each(['forums', 'gallery', 'gallery.kitchen', 'gallery.master'],
  function(moduleName) {
    MyApp.module(moduleName, ModuleDefaults.definition);
});

// override whatever your want:
MyApp.module('forums', function(mod, app) {
  mod.type = 'forum';
  mod.addFinalizer(function() { /* take out the papers and the trash */ });
});

MyApp.start();
```

Comment: Looks like [Marionette.Module](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.6/marionette.module.html) is now deprecated. The doc recommends to use AMD/CommonJS/ES6 for modularity.